# java Threads do not finish after submission to ThreadPool

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I wanted to test some ThreadPool functionality but i run into program behavior which i cant explain. My pool does not execute all threads but only a few starting and then just hungs up.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class WorkerRunnable implements Runnable {

    private static AtomicInteger ai = new AtomicInteger();

    public void run() {
        int n = ai.incrementAndGet();

        printMsg("Starting Thread: " + n);
        for (int i = Integer.MAX_VALUE; i > 0; i--)
            for (int j = Integer.MAX_VALUE; j > 0; j--)
                for (int k = Integer.MAX_VALUE; k > 0; k--);
        printMsg("Finishing Thread: " + n);
    }

    private static synchronized void printMsg(String msg) {
        System.out.println(msg);
        System.out.flush();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Executor pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            pool.execute(new WorkerRunnable());
    }

}
```

Previous code in most cases results only in starting of first 5 threads. I cant figure out why it hangs out and does not finish any of the runnables. In some cases it executes all workers but in most the only result i get is following:

```
Starting Thread: 1
Starting Thread: 3
Starting Thread: 2
Starting Thread: 4
Starting Thread: 5
```

Edit:

This is a legitimate question regarding how the JIT compiler and the x86 instructions are compiled. This program will actually execute once the optimizer realizes the for loop doesn't do anything and then optimizes it out. It's important to understand why this works in some cases and not others. It's because the for loops take a significant amount of time, but are later optimized out.

Comment: How long have you waited? You do realize that you have a threefold for loop with max integer? This will take some time to finish, even if you don't do anything in the loop.

Comment: You do know that each thread essentially counts from `2^96 - 1` to `0`? I just wrote the three loops with some output. A full execution of the innmermost loop takes roughly a second so... this might take a while. And by "a while" I mean roughly `2^64 = 1.8 * 10^19` seconds or roughly `584 942 417 355` years.

Comment: I actually didn't meassure how long it should take to finish all tasks, but when i make threadPool size for example like 100 it runs and finishes in few seconds.